# Laravel query with if and sum

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have two tables called *trabajos* and *tecnicos*.

Trabajos Table:
id | tecnico_id | fecha_ingreso | hora_ingreso | fecha_egreso | hora_egreso

Tecnicos Table
id | nombre

Note: *fecha_ingreso* is date that the work is received. *hora_ingreso* is time that the work is received. *fecha_egreso* is date the work is completed. *hora_egreso* is time the work is completed. These details are string.

I need to create an array with the following format:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [tecnico] => Pedro
        [good] => 15
        [bad] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [tecnico] => Juan
        [good] => 19
        [bad] => 3
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [tecnico] => Martin
        [good] => 18
        [bad] => 5
    )

)
```

A technician makes a job, this job has a date/time of entry and date/time of completion. If the date/time of completion is 30 minutes more than the date/time of entry should add 1 to bad but was summarily 1 good. The array should group by technical name.

This is my query:

```
$trabajos = DB::table('trabajos')
    ->join('tecnicos', 'trabajos.responsable_diagnostico', '=', 'tecnicos.id')
    ->where('trabajos.created_at', '>=', $desde4, 'and', 'trabajos.created_at', '<=', $hasta4)
    ->select(DB::raw('tecnicos.nombre', 
        SUM(if(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('trabajos.fecha_egreso', ' ', 'trabajos.hora_egreso'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('trabajos.fecha_ingreso', ' ', 'trabajos.hora_ingreso'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))<'00:30:00',1,0) as good,
        SUM(if(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('trabajos.fecha_egreso', ' ', 'trabajos.hora_egreso'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('trabajos.fecha_ingreso', ' ', 'trabajos.hora_ingreso'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))<'00:30:00',0,1) as bad))
    ->groupBy('tecnicos.nombre')
    ->get();
```

This query shows me this error in the first IF:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ')'
```

Can you help me find the error? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enclose the entire string of `DB::raw` in quotes:

```
$trabajos = DB::table('trabajos')
    ->join('tecnicos', 'trabajos.responsable_diagnostico', '=', 'tecnicos.id')
    ->where('trabajos.created_at', '>=', 'created')
    ->where('trabajos.created_at', '<=', 'created')
    ->select(DB::raw("tecnicos.nombre,
        SUM(if(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('trabajos.fecha_egreso', ' ', 'trabajos.hora_egreso'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('trabajos.fecha_ingreso', ' ', 'trabajos.hora_ingreso'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))<'00:30:00',1,0)) as good,
        SUM(if(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('trabajos.fecha_egreso', ' ', 'trabajos.hora_egreso'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'),
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('trabajos.fecha_ingreso', ' ', 'trabajos.hora_ingreso'), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))<'00:30:00',0,1)) as bad"))
    ->groupBy('tecnicos.nombre')
    ->toSql();
```

You closed by mistake the quotes after `'tecnicos.nombre',` and PHP is throwing a syntax error because it's trying to evaluate the `if` statement that should be inside the SQL query.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, now show me error in the last sentence: ->get(); 
syntax error, unexpected ';'
there must be another mistake, they can be the ' ' in instruction CONCAT?

Comment: Yes, when I quoted the select string in the answer I inadvertently deleted a closing parenthesis. I've update the answer with the correct syntax.

Comment: Ups, now show me another error! "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as good, SUM(if(TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('trabajos.fecha_diag', ' ' at line 3" probably are the quotes that are causing problems ...

Comment: You were trying to pass two conditions to a single `where` method which is not possible. You need to have individual `where` statements for for each condition. I've update the answer. Let me know if you still get errors.

Comment: You're right. I still showing error in double quotes in the CONCAT instruction in the blank space should I leave for the concatenation ...

Comment: There were still syntax errors, this time in the SQL query syntax. The `SUM` functions were not being closed properly. I've updated my answer again. I think it should work now.